# passing arguments in python, missing 4 required positional arguments?

Tags: python, function

I am currently working on a stock calculator project for a class, and can't figure out how to pass an argument from function to function. It keeps on giving me an error type of `calculateProfit() missing 4 required positional arguments`

```
def main():
    CONTINUE = 'y'
    while CONTINUE == 'y' or CONTINUE == 'Y':
        getInfo()
        pricePerShare, numOfShares, commissionRate, shareSold = calculateProfit()
        commissionPercent, spentOnShare, spentOnCommission, totalShareSold, profit, eightPercent = displayResults()
    CONTINUE = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)")
    if (CONTINUE.lower() == "n"):
        quit
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You've defined `calculateProfit` to take 4 arguments, and you're not passing any with `calculateProfit()`.

Comment: Did you write `calculateProfit()` function your own? or is it from any other package? How is it defined?

Comment: what are the arguments in your `calculateProfit( )` function .  How you defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculateProfit()` have to be called like this `calculateProfit(a, b, c, d)`, where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` is arguments. I don't know what that arguments should be, but what your code does is assigning the result of `calculateProfit()` to `pricePerShare, numOfShares, commissionRate, shareSold`.

Maybe you had in mind something like this `calculateProfit(pricePerShare, numOfShares, commissionRate, shareSold)` ?

Comment: This worked, however, I am now getting an error named "local variable (insert variable name here) referenced before assignment." Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: Because you have no values assigned to those variables. You have to read a python tutorial. Here is the page about python variables https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_variable_types.htm. Good luck!